# HTTP Authentication Exceptions

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, http, wordpress

I need to create an authentication exception for specific folders on my Apache server.

We have a blanket password protection across our whole domain, but this prevents Wordpress from uploading files and creating folders with it's Flash uploaders. Also any upload methods from plugins are failing too with `HTTP Error 401`.

Is there any way to make an exception for `/wp-admin` and `/wp-content` folders specifically?

That way, I can add the exception to any subdomains we make that use wordpress.

I've seen many examples of doing this with IPs using `Allow From`, but not with folder names...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify this using the `LocationMatch` directive. For full details you can read the Apache Docs for [LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#locationmatch), but what you probably want it something like this:

```
<LocationMatch /wp-(admin|content)>
  Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

This should match any URLs containing either the string `/wp-admin` or `/wp-content` and apply the access restrictions `Allow from all` to them.